# MySQL import float values from txt file

Tags: mysql, import

I exported an entire table from an Oracle database with all values into a txt-file - one column contains float values in the format '**1,5**' or '**0,25**' or '**0,75**' and so on (=working hours).
I connected with my mariadb database, trying to import the txt-file into a new table I created in my mariadb database.

My *show create table* shows this for the table '**working_hours**' with float values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE work (working_hours FLOAT)engine=innodb default charset=utf8 
collate=utf8_bin;
```

Import follows like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/foldername/import.txt' INTO TABLE work 
CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY 
';\n'(working_hours);
```

The import won't store float values but cuts off everything next to the integer number. So '1,5' will be stored as '1', '0,25' as '0' and so on.
I would like to keep the format 'n,m' instead of 'n.m' and I want to calculate with the float values (how many working hours per month?)
Can I calculate with sums when I use VARCHAR instead, too?
I could not find any working solution on the internet and before I cast the float values to varchar I would like to know if that does make sense in my case.

Thanks for your advice and help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BillKarwin pointed out, MySQL doesn't support `,` as a decimal separator. So to store the numbers in your database you will need to convert them. This is almost certainly necessary as comparisons on floating point numbers stored as VARCHAR don't necessarily work - in a string comparison `'9'` is > `'19'`.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to read the data into a temporary table, then copy it across to the `work` table converting it to float on the way. You could do this by:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE w1 (working_hours VARCHAR(20));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/foldername/import.txt' INTO TABLE w1
   CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY 
   ';\n'(working_hours);
INSERT INTO work SELECT 0.0 + REPLACE(working_hours, ',', '.') FROM w1;
DROP TABLE w1
```

You can always display the values including the `,` as the decimal separator by doing the reverse replace on a `SELECT` i.e.

```
SELECT REPLACE(working_hours, '.', ',') AS working_hours
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually wanted to keep the ","separator inside mysql but if that is impossible I will do a replace inside the text file, replacing "," by "." with regular expressions and then import the column. That is easier and faster for me. I will keep your interesting script for future purposes in my vaults. :-)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support `,` as a decimal separator.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html says:

> Numbers may include . as a decimal separator.

You will have to use `.` if you want to use numeric data types or calculate sums or other arithmetic expressions.

Comment: I was afraid of that but I am glad that there are multiple ways to get back to the original format, especially on the frontend, which is where I need it for. Thank you!